# To plot forecast using dygraph in R

Tags: r, dygraphs

I just copied the forecasted data into different data frame and data looks like.

**DATA**

```
`Date GMT`     Last `Last(Lo).80` `Last(Hi).80`
1 2017-09-23 1650.000         0.000         0.000
2 2017-09-25 1650.000         0.000         0.000
3 2017-09-26 1655.000         0.000         0.000
4 2017-09-27 1653.000         0.000         0.000
5 2017-09-28 1652.210      1650.763      1653.657
6 2017-09-29 1652.714      1649.952      1655.477
7 2017-09-30 1653.238      1648.940      1657.536
8 2017-10-01 1654.264      1648.251      1660.278
```

**CODE**

```
  s <-subset(d1, select = c(1,5,6,7))
   dygraph(s, main ="Price chart") %>% 
             dyRangeSelector() %>% 
             dyRangeSelector(height = 40,
             dateWindow = c("2017-09-23", "2017-10-01")) %>%
             dySeries(name = "actuals", label = "actual") %>%
             dySeries(c(2,3,4), label = "Predicted") %>%
             dyLegend(show = "always", hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
             dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5,
             highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 2)) %>%
             dyOptions(axisLineColor = "navy", gridLineColor = "grey")
```

And while running this i am getting error of Unsupported data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input your data in `dygraph` as a time series object.

```
d1 <- read.table(text="
'Date GMT'     'Last' 'Last(Lo).80' 'Last(Hi).80'
1 2017-09-23 1650.000         0.000         0.000
2 2017-09-25 1650.000         0.000         0.000
3 2017-09-26 1655.000         0.000         0.000
4 2017-09-27 1653.000         0.000         0.000
5 2017-09-28 1652.210      1650.763      1653.657
6 2017-09-29 1652.714      1649.952      1655.477
7 2017-09-30 1653.238      1648.940      1657.536
8 2017-10-01 1654.264      1648.251      1660.278
", header=T)
d1$Date.GMT <- as.POSIXct(d1$Date.GMT, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")

library(tseries)
ts1 <- irts(time=d1[,1], value=as.matrix(d1[,2:4]))

library(dygraphs)
dygraph(ts1, main ="Price chart") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector() %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(height = 40,
     dateWindow = c("2017-09-23", "2017-10-01")) %>%
  dyLegend(show = "always", hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5,
     highlightSeriesOpts = list(strokeWidth = 2)) %>%
  dyOptions(axisLineColor = "navy", gridLineColor = "grey")
```

[image]